# How to add a file to first commit?

Tags: git

My repo has 2000 commits on master branch. I want to add a LICENSE file to the very first commit, then rebase all other commits on top of that, so that all commits have LICENSE file.

My steps:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

In editor, I change "pick" to "edit" on very first commit.

Then, add a LICENSE:

```
cp ~/Desktop/LICENSE .
git add LICENSE
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

First ~80 commits are rebased successfully, but then I get merge conflicts. How to get rid of them?

Note: I tried to add `--rebase-merges` to `git rebase` - same effect.

Note: I also tried to run `rerere-teach.sh <initial commit hash>`, and enabled rerere by default: `rerere.enabled 1`. Still getting those merge conflicts.

Comment: Since you are modifying history, you might end up getting conflicts. You have to resolve those and continue. There are numerous guides online on how to resolve git conflicts, but essentially, you open the conflict file, fix the indicated conflict, then "git add", and then finally "git rebase --continue". You are likely going to get conflicts on every commit that modifies the same file, so expect to fix multiple conflicts.

Comment: @Automatico I know how to resolve conflicts. Point is that I don't want to duplicate this effort in every merge. There are too many conflicts and I may end up breaking the code if I resolve them manually, therefore I asked for a solution that does not require resolving them.

Comment: In practice, you should be getting one conflict per commit that modifies the license. You can possibly use the "git rebase -X thers" (or "ours", whichever is correct in your case), and hope that it works out. When modifying history you need to "resolve" your conflicts somehow. You can't simply make the conflicts go away, but in this case you should never get conflicts for anything other than the license file. If you are, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Conflicts that I get are unrelated to LICENSE file :( They come from merge commits, AFAIK.

Comment: This sounds strange. Perhaps my git-Foo isn't strong enough, but I believe that if you rebase from a clean state to the same branch with no changes, it should never produce a conflict. Perhaps you were on a different branch or something when you started the rebase?

Comment: I believe that you don't have to do the commit part of your example by the way. Maybe that is causing issues. Git add, and then rebase --continue should be enough.

Comment: If I don't do a change, then rebase works. But the whole point of an "edit" is to add LICENSE file.

Comment: mass rewriting tools such as `git filter-branch` or [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) would be more suitable.

See [this item in git filter-repo example sections](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_parent_rewriting_2) for a starting point.